# How to look for repeated rows and then delete one of them?

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if anyone knows how to delete repeated rows.. Say for example,

```
   A        B       C

1  1        3       4
2  2        6       9
3  TEST     1       2
4  TEST     1       2
5  Both     1
6  Hi               2
7  None     3       3
8  Loud     4       4
```

For the particular example above, TEST was repeated twice.. In some other cases, the name can be some other kinds such as NOON, Morning, etc.. And row 8 does not necessary be the last row.
I have no idea of how to compare the rows to check for repeated names and then delete them away. I need to run a macro with this and so i will need VBA. If you know it, please share it with me.. Will be thankful!

Attempt for codes:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim LastRow As Long, n As Long, rowstodelete As Long

    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For n = 1 To LastRow

        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 1)
            If .Cells(n, 1) = .Cells(n + 1, 1) Then
                rowstodelete = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 1)
                Rows(rowstodelete).Select
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        End With
    Next n
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, there were runtime error over at the .Cells(n, 1).. I have no idea why it is.. if you know something can share with me or modify it alittle. will be thankful!

Comment: Rather than duplicate rows (ie A2,B2,C3 match A3,B3 and C3 etc) it appears you only want to delete records in column A that are duplicates. When deleting rows it is best to delete bottom up to avoid skipping rows.

Comment: +1 Agreed on "Bottom Up"

Comment: I think you may have missed my one line VBA solution in my post below

Comment: If you are using Excel 07/10 then I would recommend the one line solution which @brettdj suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is recommended that when deleting rows, always do it in reverse mode. See this code. Also you do not need to select the cell before deleting. That will slow down your code :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim LastRowcheck As Long, n1 As Long
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRowcheck = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        For n1 = LastRowcheck To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(n1, 1).Value = Cells(n1 + 1, 1).Value Then
               .Rows(n1).Delete
            End If
        Next n1
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is an even better and **faster** way.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim LastRowcheck As Long, n1 As Long
    Dim DelRange As Range
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRowcheck = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        For n1 = 1 To LastRowcheck
            If .Cells(n1, 1).Value = Cells(n1 + 1, 1).Value Then
                If DelRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set DelRange = .Rows(n1)
                Else
                    Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, .Rows(n1))
                End If
            End If
        Next n1
        
        If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> any idea why reverse row deletion is better? – franklin 29 secs ago

When you delete a row, your `For` loop messes up as you are targeting set number of rows. You have to then write extra line of code , as you did, to keep track of the rows that you deleted. It also slows down your code :) When you delete in reverse then you don't have to account for the deleted row as it falls out of the **current** running loop. This way your code is faster. But then like I mentioned above, if you are not using reverse row deletion then use the 2nd code that I gave. That is even faster.

One point that I would like to mention though. If you are using Excel 2007/2010 then the one line code that @brettdj suggested is the fastest :)

Comment: any idea why reverse row deletion is better?

Comment: @SiddharthRout : I'm undergoing similiar situations described in the question. I tried your code but getting error `'Union' is not declared.` Please help.

Comment: @slyclam: That's probably because you have some missing reference. Do this. In VBA Editor, Click on Tools | References and uncheck any missing references and then try again :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout : Could you possibly look at my question once. Can't get it to work. Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952867/getting-count-of-duplicate-entries-in-an-excel-column-using-vb-net). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @slyclam: Sorry cant post an answer. The question is already closed as Offtopic :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I have posted new question with code in it. Could you please have a look ? Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361925/sorting-values-of-an-excel-column-by-max-occurrences-using-vb-net).

Comment: what if i need to limit the range from A:AC ?? and then display it with highlighting red??

Answer (score 4):

**Manual**
[Bill Jelen's website](http://www.mrexcel.com/tip138.shtml) offers three non-VBA techniques

1. ***All Versions:*** Use the Unique Option in Advanced Filter
2. ***Xl 07/10:*** Use Conditional Formatting to Mark Duplicates
3. ***Xl 07/10:*** Use Remove Duplicates icon

For (3) the equivalent VBA would be something like this (for no headers)
`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo`

[image]

**Handling existing duplicates**
My free [Duplicate Master addin](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2123-Eliminating-duplicate-data-with-Duplicate-Master-V2.html) will let you

- Select
- Colour
- List
- Delete

duplicates on either cells, entire rows (which appears to be your question) or certain columns in a row

But more importantly it will let you run more complex matching than exact strings, ie

- Case Insensitive / Case Sensitive searches
- Trim/Clean data
- Remove all blank spaces (including CHAR(160))
- Run regular expression matches
- Match on any combination of columns (ie Column A, all columns, Column A&B etc)
  [image]

Comment: hi, i need vba.. i'm running macro.. that's why.

Comment: @user1204868 well you didn't specify that requirement in your question. My addin is a macro solution, but menu driven rather then one you can directly code.

Comment: Oh.. i'm sorry. I wasnt aware of that as i thought maybe with the tags for VBA and VBA excel, it should be quite clear.. will take note of that.. btw, do u have any idea on the coding?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I was able to come up with my own code! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @user1204868 its not always clear as sometime someone doesn't realise that there is a non-VBA solution which they may prefer. So I thought I had you covered with both a non-VBA and addin results. If you needed a customisable macro its good for us to know that upfront. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted my code once again and it can work out well.. Thanks! I will share it here to answer similar questions in the future!

```
  Sub Macro1()

  Dim LastRowcheck As Long, n1 As Long, rowschecktodelete As Long

  LastRowcheck = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  For n1 = 1 To LastRowcheck
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n1, 1)
      If Cells(n1, 1) = Cells(n1 + 1, 1) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(n1, 1).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
     End If
   End With
  Next n1

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this in VBA (in 2007 or higher):

`Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates(Array(1, 2, 3))`

Depending on your worksheet layout you might need to adjust `Range("A1").CurrentRegion` to your data range...

Comment: how to make `Array(1, 2, 3)` dynamic

Comment: @shareef In what regard do you want to make it dynamic? Number of elements or which columns? You can obviously change `Array(1, 2, 3)` to any other array according to your needs...

Comment: thanks for the reply actually i solved it and post my answer to my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195792/vba-making-a-column-number-variabl-array-for-removeduplicates/36195793#36195793

Answer (score -3):

I think we need to sort the data first before running this macro to remove the duplicates completely.