# Delete partial rows in VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

T'm trying to format *n* ranges of 4 columns like below, expanding to the right and separated by a blank column (col "E"). The range 2 starts at column "F".

> range 1
>
> A     B               C     D ...
>
> X     Action1     X     X
>           -
>           -
>   X     Action2     X     X
>   X     Action3     X     X
>         #N/A     #N/A     #N/A

For each range, I want to remove rows (of 4 columns) containing "-" on the second column or "#N/A" on any column of the range, expecting this result :

> range 1
>
> A     B               C     D ...
>
> X     Action1     X     X
>   X     Action2     X     X
>   X     Action3     X     X

This is a part of a VBA macro so I won't use manual autofilters. On top, autofiltering would remove also rows from other ranges, which is not expected.

I'm trying this code at least for testing on the 1st block, even not working :

```
Dim Rng As Range
  Set Rng = Range("A4", "D53")
  If Not Rng(, 2).Value = "-" Then
    Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
  End If
```

edit : I guess the answer may not be far away from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9654346/461212) but I can't manage it properly.

Lost in VBA, some help would be great, thx in advance

**EDIT**: if it may help someone, I ended up with this working code thx to the below hints :

```
Dim iRows, iCols, NbLig, x, BlockSize, BlockOffset, MyOffsetBtwnBlocks, CountBlocks As Integer


    BlockSize = 4

    NbLig = Range("A3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    CountBlocks = 0

    For iCols = 2 To NbCol Step BlockSize + 1

        iRows = Range(Cells(3, iCols), Cells(NbLig, iCols + BlockSize).End(xlToLeft)).Rows.Count

        For x = iRows To 3 Step -1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(x, iCols + 1)) Then
                Application.Intersect(Cells(x, iCols + 1).EntireRow, _
                     Range(Cells(3, iCols), Cells(3, iCols + BlockSize)).EntireColumn).Delete

            ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(x, iCols + 2)) Then
                Application.Intersect(Cells(x, iCols + 2).EntireRow, _
                     Range(Cells(3, iCols), Cells(3, iCols + BlockSize)).EntireColumn).Delete

            ElseIf Cells(x, iCols + 1).Value = "-" Then
                Application.Intersect(Cells(x, iCols + 1).EntireRow, _
                     Range(Cells(3, iCols), Cells(3, iCols + BlockSize)).EntireColumn).Delete

            End If

            CountBlocks = CountBlocks + 1

        Next x

    Next iCols
```

Comment: You can either use that or you can use Autofilter. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317172/delete-row-based-on-condition)

Comment: Except that I do not want to delete the entire row but only the column range of the current block.

Comment: True :) You cn easily amend the code to suit your needs :)

Comment: Was the autofilter code too difficult to understand?

Comment: Yes as I have no background in VBA, and especially I had a doubt to risk to delete the entire row but I want to delete only 4 columns on a row.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see a comment above which says "Sid, I tried it but was stuck. This is the code that I tried. Could you please help me out?" Anyways... you got your answer so lets leave it at that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do you:

```
Sub RemoveX()
    Dim iRows As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    iRows = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    For x = iRows To 1 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Cells(x, 2)) Then
            Application.Intersect(Cells(x, 2).EntireRow, _
                Range("A1:D1").EntireColumn).Delete
        ElseIf Cells(x, 2).Value = "-" Then
            Application.Intersect(Cells(x, 2).EntireRow, _
                Range("A1:D1").EntireColumn).Delete
        End If
    Next x
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

`CurrentRegion` is the region obtained if you click into A1 and press Ctrl-A.

If could be tidied up a little (using Range references and not using EntireRow or -Column) but it works.

Comment: Thx - I edit my updated code solution - working despite not that nice.

Comment: Not that nice - cheek!! ;)