# Sorting values of an excel column by max occurrences using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have an excel file which has column B1 to B500 (may vary) filled with numbers. For example:

```
![sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSkLt.jpg)
```

I need the output to be like:

```
![sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTqEK.jpg)
```

I have this much code till now:

```
 Sub Max()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim cl As Excel.Range

    i = 1
    j = 1
    For i = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        cl = sheet.Cells(i, 2) '## Examine the cell in Column B
        If xl.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sheet.Range("B:B"), cl.Value) > 1 Then
            cl.Value = sheet.Cells(j, 3).value 'copy to Column C
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

What this code does is to find duplicates in column B and remove other entries from the column. Nothing gets written in column C. I want the column B to be unedited at the end. Also cannot figure out how to achieve the sorting here.

Please help.

Comment: So you want to get a list of all unique values (no duplicates) in column B, and then put them all in column C but sorted in descending order?

Comment: @rwisch45: not unique values. I want column C to be filled (in descending order) with the mostly repeated value in column B. The count of repetitions will be in column D.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use formulas if you want too:

[image: Static Sort Using Excel Formulas - lmiguelmh]

It is very important to use array formulas (Ctrl+Shift+Enter when done editing the cell), my Excel is an Spanish Version, so you just need to change: 
 - SI by IF
 - CONTAR.SI by COUNT.IF

I came up with this solution thinking about the [bubble sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). I hope this will be useful for you.