# How to step through excel rows with VBA macro and insert duplicate row if value changes

Tags: vba, excel

I need to insert an additional record before the next value in a list changes.

```
1   4   j
2   4   g
3   5   h
4   5   f
5   5   v
6   5   y
7   5   f
8   6   f
9   6   g
10  8   j
```

ie Lines 2, 7, 9 would be duplicated and inserted before the next line. Note working is from the bottom up. I thought maybe Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

```
Sub InsertRowsWithNewValues()
' Note: hard coded to "Sheet1", ChkCol
    Dim LastRowcheck As Long, n1 As Long, ChkCol As Long

ChkCol = 2
MsgBox ("Execute on column: " + Str(ChkCol))

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRowcheck = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For n1 = LastRowcheck To 3 Step -1
MsgBox (.Cells(n1, ChkCol).Value + " " + .Cells(n1 - 1, ChkCol).Value)
            If .Cells(n1, ChkCol).Value <> Cells(n1 - 1, ChkCol).Value Then
               .Rows(n1).Insert
               .Rows(n1 - 1).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Selection.Insert
'               .Rows(n1).Paste
            End If
        Next n1
    End With
End Sub
```

[Reference Here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644453/how-to-look-for-repeated-rows-and-then-delete-one-of-them-requires-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved without VBA, assuming `h` is in B3:

Select ColumnsA:B, DATA > Outline - Subtotal At each change in: `4`, Use function: Count, Add subtotal to: tick `j`, tick Replace current subtotals, tick Summary below data, OK.

Filter ColumnsA:B, for ColumnA select Number Filters, Custom Filter..., contains, `c`, OK, Delete all visible below Row1, filter for (Select All), select ColumnsA:B, HOME > Editing - Find & Select, Go To Special..., select Blanks, OK.

`=`, Up, Ctrl+Enter. Remove Filter, select entire sheet, DATA > Outline - Ungroup, Clear Outline. Delete any surplus at the bottom.

Comment: There are other things that I need to do to this file in VBA as ascii input to another program.

Comment: It is disappointing to see this thread asking for a VBA solution hijacked by a manual solution.