# VBA: Making a Column Number Variabl Array for .RemoveDuplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stumped on this one and haven't been able to find the answer through search.

This comes from the macro-recorder when I remove duplicates from the last 3 columns of my range.

```
Sub Macro1()
' Macro1 Macro
    Range("A1:E8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$8").RemoveDuplicates _
        Columns:=Array(3, 4, 5), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

I want to make a macro that does this using variables instead of Array(3, 4, 5)
but I get an error when trying to pass an array built from variables.

```
Sub MyTry1()
    Dim iArray() As Integer, i As Integer
    With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$8")
        ReDim iArray(1 To .Columns.Count - 2)
        For i = 1 To 3
            iArray(i) = i + 2
        Next i  'Result is iArray= (3, 4, 5)      
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=iArray, Header:=xlYes
       'returns Run-time error "5": Invalid procedure call or argument
    End With
End Sub
```

I've tried Integer, Long and Variant data types, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a zero-based Variant Array of Integers and wrap the Array Reference in **parentheses** as shown below

```
Sub MyTry2()
    Dim iArray As Variant, i As Integer
    Dim rData As Range
    Set rData = Range("$A$1:$E$8")
    With rData
        ReDim iArray(0 To .Columns.Count - 3)
        For i = 0 To UBound(iArray)
            iArray(i) = i + 3
        Next i
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(iArray), Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```