# Excel Macro VBA basic comparison - but unable to fix error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of rows and columns range is **A:AC** and Rows count may be anything

**Fixing the sheet and range and calculating RowCount and ColumnCount using this**

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
LastRow = sheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastColumn = sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
Set selectedRange = Range("A1:AC" & LastRow)
```

- **First Condition:**

I am trying to compare column F to AC should have either 0 or 1. and found that by using

```
For i =1 To LastRow
   For j = 6 To LastColumn
      If Cells(i, j).Value <> 0 And Cells(i, j) <> 1 Then
           Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = vbGreen
      End If
      If Cells(i, j).Value > 1 Then
           Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = vbRed
      End If
   Next j
Next i
```

- **Second Condition**

Out of these columns I should have only **one column** should have **1** and remaining as **0**

**I tried this and it is throwing different error codes for each run**

- **Third Condition**

Find **duplicate rows** from A:AC

I need to highlight entire **row** which has the error

**`But I have done which Column has error`** with this statement 
**`Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = vbRed`**

### Though it is simple I am unable to figure out the logic as I am completely new to Excel VBA.

Comment: range("blah").entirerow for the whole row to start

Comment: (a) Note that `Set selectedRange = Range("A1:AC" & LastRow)` is selecting a range on the active sheet, not on the sheet your other statements are accessing.  You probably want to say `Set selectedRange = sheet.Range("A1:AC" & LastRow)` - but you don't appear to be using selectedRange elsewhere so it probably doesn't matter. (b) Similarly, all the references to `Cells` in your "first condition" block are accessing the active sheet - you probably need `sheet.Cells`.

Comment: you may want to add a "before" and "after" scenarios images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first condition:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 6 To LastColumn
        Select Case Cells(i, j).Value
            Case 0
                Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            Case 1
                Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed

            Case Else
                Cells(i, j) = "Whetever"
        End Select
        if range("A" & i).value = 1 and range("AC" & i).value = 1 then
            Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        end if
   Next j
Next i
```

Point 2 now added.  For deleting duplicates, that depends on your data, but the question has been asked here:

[How to look for repeated rows and then delete one of them? requires VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644453/how-to-look-for-repeated-rows-and-then-delete-one-of-them-requires-vba)

Comment: I made first condition but in the first one I want to add the second one also instead of adding another set of for loop.