# I have to run my code several times for it to execute entirely

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm not sure whether it's because I'm using a mac or the code is wrong, but the rows aren't identifying properly, and therefore not deleting or pasting it into the other spreadsheet. I have to run the code three times for it to properly go through it and copy/paste and delete the cells into the other spreadsheet.

Many thanks!

here is the code:

```
Dim j, lastidno As Long


Sheets("Part B + C Modules").Activate
lastidno = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Count + 1
For j = 2 To lastidno
If Range("O" & j) = "" Then
Sheets("Part B + C Modules").Range("A" & j).Copy
            Sheets("No Options Selected").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Part B + C Modules").Activate
Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next

MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

Comment: When deleting rows, always start from the bottom. Here each time two rows that should be deletes are next one each other, the second one is skipped (because after the first one is deleted, the indexes of the next rows are changed) See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603351/how-to-delete-rows-in-a-loop

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iteration and deleting rows goes backwards using a negative `Step` > `For j = lastidno to 2 Step -1`

However, it appears you could rewrite your code a bit more elegantly to avoid:

- Implicit `Range` references
- Iteration
- Use of `Activate` or `Select`

The key is to have `Explicit` sheet references to work with. Also the use of `SpecialCells` can come in handy here to return a `Range` in one go (so no more iteration). This way you can also delete all rows in one go!

You code could, for example, look like:

```
Sub Test()

'Set up your worksheet variables
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Worksheets("Part B + C Modules")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Worksheets("No Options Selected")

'Get last used rows
Dim lr1 As Long: lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim lr2 As Long: lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Set your range and copy it
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws1.Range("O2:O" & lr1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(0, -14)
rng.Copy ws2.Cells(lr2 + 1, 1)

'Delete your range
rng.EntireRow.Delete

MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

Small catch: `SpecialCells` will return an error when no empty cells are found. You might want to work your way around that using `On error` or count the empty cells in your `Range` first (my personal preference). So that specific part could looke like:

```
'Set your range and copy it
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ws1.Range("O2:O" & lr1)) > 0 Then
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws1.Range("O2:O" & lr1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(0, -14)
    rng.Copy ws2.Cells(lr2 + 1, 1)
End If
```

Another small note for future reference: `Dim j, lastidno As Long` only has `lastidno` declared as `Long` data type. `j` Variable is auto-assigned to `Variant/Integer` so could potentially become a problem when your data is larger than this data type can hold > Return an `OverFlow` error.